# Facebook API Registration

Tags: facebook

1)If two users(A & B) logs into the website(http://site.com). Both(A & B) have registered in the website with normal user registration (not FB register). Both(A & B) will have access to all parts of the site with all user provisions.They can write their reviews in the website and can do so and so.This is happening right now.

Note:Let us assume the users A and B are already friends in the Facebook.But they don't know each other in our website.

2)If two users(X & Y) logs into the website. Both(X & Y) have registered in the website with facebook registration. Both(X & Y) will have access to all parts of the site with all user provisions.They can write their reviews in the website and can do so and so.This is happening right now.

Note:Let us assume the users X and Y are already friends in the Facebook.But they don't know each other in our website.

What i am  going to do:

a)If the user A logs into the system, we need to show facebook login button in some page to link his facebook account. If he wish to link , he need to give his FB login details,then we need to show the friends of him who are all also the users of my website. He may have so many friends with his facebook account, but in this part we need to show B details because he is already user of the site and also his facebook friend as we stated above.

If the user A has someother facebook friends(D,E,F) who are also registered users in our site  then we will need to show all of those user details with their  recent activity in the website under his FB linking page.

2)This is the samething need to do for FB registered users(X,Y) also.(Similar to http://runkeeper.com)

Technical Agenda:

1)First type of user(A,B):

```
   During the linking of facebook(facebook login), we are going to update the user table row values with his facebook details and then we need to show his FB friends activity in the website by using the FB session data  created for his/her FB login and now i will be able to show his Friendslist.
```

Problem:

The same user(A or B) logout from the website and relogin with his user login details. In the user table we already having his facebook id details, using that we need to show all of his FB friends. The Facebook api uses the Session value to show the datas with the api call like $frnd=$facebook->api('/me').Now there is no session for this user.

```
Please suggest me anyway to come up with this technical part , because there is no clear documentation to follow .
```

2)Second type of user(X,Y):

```
    They are going to login with the existing FB details to the site, we need to just show there FB friend activity in the website.
```

Comment: on your user table, keep a field of FB_ID, than every time a user login through facebook request all of his friends and see if any of the users have on of those FB_ID's..... also, you should keep a friends table.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am doing it so in my user table, but i don't need to ask user to relogin with their FB details at all the times if they have linked with the FB account for the first time.If the user table has its FB_ID,FB_EMAIL i need to show there friends details without the other tables.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and got the solution exactly what i need.Thanks for your suggestion mate.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible as you describe. What web platform are you using for your site. PHP, ASP.NET, or another? As you have experienced, the documentation is sometimes lacking. If you are using php, it will likely be a little easier to get everything working, because the examples all seem to be in php.

I will have to give you a more detailed answer tomorrow, but I will need to know which platform you are using for your website. Also, it wasn't very clear to me, did you say that users are already logging in to your site using facebook authentication?

Eric

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate.Sorry for my english which makes me down to explain better.I am using PHP.
**Detailed Explanation**:
User login into the site with his login details. What i have to do at this point, we need to check the user table for his login details(uname,pwd) & FB details. 1)If he do have facebook details(fbid,fbemail) in the user table, then we need to retreive his FB friends details by using those details. We don't need to ask them to flogin with their flogin details again. This is main thing making problem for me, because the FB API works based on the session values.

Comment: Excepting your kind explanation about this part.

Comment: hi eupton, could you please provide me some specification about my queries